# How can I set View (editor) options programmatically?

Tags: configuration, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I want to make sure that all team members use the same editor settings in QTP.

But while the global options (Tools/Options) dialog's configuration options are readily addressable using OTA (using the `.Options` object), I cannot find any documentation regarding programmatic access to the the view options (Tools/View Options) dialog´s configuration options.

After some digging, I see that `QTEditor.ini`, located in QTP's `bin` subdirectory, contains the settings of whcih I want to reset some.

**So is there an API solution (comparable to QTP's `Options` object) to modify the view options, or do I have to manipulate the ini file directly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The QTP view (or: editor) settings seem not to be covered by any known API, so one has to manipulate the ini file directly.**

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do that in pure VBScript: you'd want to use the `WritePrivateProfileStringA` `KERNEL32` `WINAPI` function for that, even though it is phased out, but since **VBScript does not support DLL imports**, the remaining options are:

1. write a COM DLL wrapper for `WritePrivateProfileStringA` , and call that one (overkill)
2. or write your own INI file parser (and writer) in VBScript (overkill, too, if you ask me)
3. remember that QTP has the nice `Extern.Declare` method which indeed allows to call DLL functions, and use that one to call `WritePrivateProfileStringA`.

**I went for option 3. That means the "resetter" script is a QTP test**, not a compact VBScript, but heaven cannot exist without hell, so what.

If anybody is interested in the source, I'll post it on request.